# Math autocompletion in org mode

Tags: org-mode, latex

What is the easiest way to get autocompletion for math symbols when I write latex formulas between `\(..\)` or `\[...\]` in **org-mode**?

Could packages like [company-math](https://github.com/vspinu/company-math) or [ac-math](https://github.com/vspinu/ac-math) be used in org-mode, for example? How should I configure them to use them in org-mode?

Comment: I'm using company-math to insert unicode math notation in all modes in my config: https://github.com/malb/emacs.d/blob/master/malb.org#latex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `LaTeX-math-mode` from the AucTex package. This provides quick completion of common math macros like `\alpha`, `\sum`, `\Sigma` etc.  Make sure the package is loaded with the following line in your `.emacs`:

```
(require 'latex)
```

And then from your org-mode buffer turn on `latex-math-mode` with `M-x latex-math-mode`. This provides shortcuts for a number of math symbols. You start by entering the backtick symbol "`". The next key will add a LaTeX macro. For example, `a` inserts `\alpha`, `C-_` inserts `\inf`, etc. The full list is available on the [auctex reference card](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/auctex/11.86-extra/tex-ref.pdf), and you can add your own shortcuts by customizing the variable `LaTeX-math-list`.

Entering two backticks in a row inserts a plain backtick. You can change the prefix key if you don't want to use the backtick - see the customization option `LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix`.

If you have more complex completion needs, you can use company-mode, yasnippet etc. I don't think there is anything special about configuring these for use with org-mode, relative to any other Emacs mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [polymode](https://github.com/polymode) for this. See also [this](https://github.com/polymode/poly-org/issues/27) discussion about how to set it up.