# LaTeX tags autocomplete in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, auto-complete-mode

Absolute beginner with Emacs and Emacs Lisp. I am using `spacemacs` and have been trying to  get autocompletion of matching delimiters commonly used in LaTeX in Org-mode. My requirements are just getting the matching delimiters autocompleted. This is different from [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26322/math-autocompletion-in-org-mode) but more similar to [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12806/17931).

- when I type `\(` and press `TAB`, it should autocomplete it to `\( | \)` and leave the cursor at the position where `|` is.
- Similarly, when I type `\[` and press `TAB`, it should autocomplete to `\[ | \]` and leave the cursor at the position where `|` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get exactly the behavior you describe if you put the following code in your init file.
It re-binds the tab key to a new command `org-cycle-or-complete-latex`.
At a <kbd>tab</kbd> keystroke `org-cycle-or-complete-latex` looks first whether point is behind `\(` or `\[` and completes the math equation in this case otherwise it just runs `org-cycle` -- the normal binding of <kbd>tab</kbd>  in org-mode.

```el
(defun org-cycle-or-complete-latex (&optional arg)
  "Like `org-cycle' (which see) but completes latex math equations
if point is after ＼[ or ＼(."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (looking-back "\\\\[[(]" (max (point-min) (- (point) 2)))
      (progn
    (insert
     (case (char-before)
       (?\( "  \\)")
       (?\[ "  \\]")
       (t (error "Should never happen."))))
    (backward-char 3))
    (call-interactively #'org-cycle)))

(defun my-org-mode-hook-fun ()
  (org-defkey org-mode-map [(tab)] #'org-cycle-or-complete-latex))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-mode-hook-fun)
```

Comment: Why not put that mechanism in org-mode pcomplete ?

Comment: @startdiviner Don't you have to press `M-tab` for pcomplete instead of `tab`?

Comment: I use company to complete in org-mode. And org provide some place pcomplete.